# Is there a better way to store my functions on one server to use on multiple servers?

Tags: php

Here is my quick code. This allows me to keep one file for my commonly used PHP functions, and retrieve it as needed. This is mostly my private work and not for clients.

```
$include_contents = '<?php '.file_get_contents("http://example.com/inc/functions.php");  
$handle = fopen("_functions.php", 'w');  
fputs($handle, $include_contents );  
fclose($handle);  
include('_functions.php');
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: To put the above another way: what do you gain by doing this? (Nothing -- the question is rhetorical).

Comment: Nice security hole. Good work! Note: A hacker could introspect the connection between the application and the server where the code is stored. So he can at least read the code, but he can also change it.

Comment: You shouldn't do this, it's a *really* horrible idea. You're making an additional HTTP request for every page requested, and if that HTTP request fails, all sites referencing your code are unusable. Just copy the file into your projects.

Comment: I'd sincerely hope this wasn't for clients, else I'd be looking for a new developer if I was a client

Comment: I want to store simple functions, such as echoing out the current URL with a simple _url() command. Just a place to keep some non critical functions which I use often.

Comment: Yeah, **don't do that**. Copy the file into your project. You're solving a problem that really doesn't exist in the first place, and introducing huge problems in the process.

Comment: I'm 100% open to ideas, but google returns nothing simple like this. If there is no sensitive data in the file, what's the problem with calling it like this as far as security goes?

Comment: If the server is down, that's another problem, all your websites will be offline. Not to mention that remote include are very slow. **DON'T DO IT! NEVER!**

Comment: Yep, just keep a git repo or similar of all your common code to keep it centralized, then pull it in alongside each project (essentially giving a bit sanity to managing the same code copied everywhere).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't do it!**

The better way of doing this is to just host all the files you need on the local filesystem and include/require them normally.

There are no advantages to the approach you're suggesting, and numerous disadvantages of such severity that there is nothing whatsoever to be gained by doing this.

If the host that provides all your includes goes down, then every site that uses them goes down too.  Even if it doesn't go down the extra latency of doing an additional http request to include the remote file will add to the total execution time of your script.

Worse, is the remote server is compromised, or your DNS server is co-opted to point the remote site's domain to a malicious server, a hacker can introduce malicious code with ease.

Servers typically have huge amounts of storage available, there's no reason why you can't keep all your PHP scripts on the server that the pages they generate will be served from.

Note: if you insist in persisting with such insanity as this, you can enable allow_url_include and then you can include directly from a URL.

But like I said, this is a really really REALLY bad idea, and there's a reason why allow_url_include is off by default.

Comment: Thanks, no one really explained WHY it's bad. I can't learn unless things are explained how they work. So in essence, the security issue is if the .php file was compromised. What if it were hosted on Amazon S3 with great redundency... then we wouldn't have to worry about that file going down. Also I understand it slows down the load time, another negative. Most replies are treating me like a 5 year old, but not explaining the reasoning behind their yelling. The idea behind this is that my sites are not all on the same server. I'll just copy my functions.php file in the future.

Comment: If you've got an architecture that requires different servers to provide different parts of the task for whatever reason, a better approach is to have each server have whatever PHP scripts are needed to accomplish the particular task the server needs to do, and have the scripts on the various servers intercommunicate with a standard text format such as JSON or XML.  Both are well-supported in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a deployment strategy. [`Composer`](http://getcomposer.org/) should be a good starting point to investigate. It is a software, written in PHP, that aims to resolve external dependencies, but not at runtime, at installation time. Start with the link I gave you.

Beside from composer there are other deployment strategies and softwares for PHP, the most notable (but needs more effort to make it work) is [PEAR](http://pear.php.net/package/PEAR/redirected) or even [PEAR2](http://pear2.php.net/)

Comment: Composer is good as a dependency manager, but it isn't a deployment tool... use something like `Capistrano` or `phing` for managing deployments

Comment: I'm using PEAR, and good! ;) Btw, don't care too much about that word `dependency manager`.. Of course composer can be used to deploy php packages.

Comment: Never seen it actually used to do a deployment, I'll have to read up a bit more

Comment: AFAIK it has no capabilities like installation hook scripts, so it's less powerful for whole application deployment (with database etc). But it is at least useful for deploying libraries and keep them up to date.. Have also a look at [packagist](https://packagist.org/). It's a repository of existing packages

Comment: Yeah, I've heard of packagist too... I'm guessing that you use composer to deploy by sshing to the webserver and running composer against the composer.json - I think I prefer using Capistrano for a "one touch" deployment, especially for complex deployments across multiple servers

Comment: Will read about `Capistrano`.. Never heard about. Note that I rarely use composer. I just support this type of installation for my packages (no one except me has installed so far ;)... I'm preferring good old PEAR, or for applications that need more syswork while installation I use `.deb` packages for `apt`. This has been working good even on large projects, with many target servers (at work) since years